# How do I make my own generic functional list implementation in Java behave covariantly?

Tags: java, functional-programming, concatenation, singly-linked-list, covariance

I am implementing my own linked list in Java mainly as an attempt to learnt the syntax. I have some experience in Scala, and am trying to implement a functional, immutable linked list. I'm having trouble understanding how to make a covariant concatenation method. I want to be able to concatenate (append) a `List<Sub>` with (to) a `List<Super>`.

```
public abstract List<T> {
    public abstract T head();
    public abstract List<T> tail();
    public abstract boolean isEmpty();
    // ... more methods
    public List<T> concat(List<? extends T> that) {
        if (this.isEmpty()) return (List<T>) that; // Gross
        else return new Cons<>(this.head(), this.tail().concat(that));
    }
}
public class Cons<T> extends List<T> {
    private final T head;
    private final List<T> tail;
    public boolean isEmpty() {return false;}
    public Cons(T head, List<T> tail) {this.head = head; this.tail = tail;}
    public T head() {return head;}
    public List<T> tail() {return tail;}
}
public class Nil<T> extends List<T> {
    public T head() {throw new NoSuchElementException();}
    public List<T> tail() {throw new NoSuchElementException();}
    public boolean isEmpty() {return true;}
}
```

I seem to only be able to do this by explicitly casting the list of subtypes to a list of supertypes which seems ugly. I'm essentially trying to mimic Scala's `List[+T]` covariance formalism. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as Java is concerned, a `List<Subclass>` isn't a `List<Superclass>`, and there's no way to tell it otherwise. Neither covariance nor contravariance is supported.

I can think of a few options here:

1. Declare `concat` as returning `List<? extends T>`, rather than promising that it will return exactly `List<T>`.
2. Do what you're doing — *you* know that, since your `List` class is immutable, it's safe to reinterpret a `List<Subclass>` as a `List<Superclass>`, so you can just cast it, plus an appropriate `@SuppressWarnings` annotation with a comment. (You'll probably want to centralize this in a private `upcast` method.)
3. Declare `Cons.tail` as having type `List<? extends T>`, and whenever you need to convert from `List<? extends Superclass>` to `List<Superclass>`, you can do so by destructuring and reconstructing — creating a new `Cons<Superclass>` or `Nil<Superclass>` with the same fields. (The reason to declare `Cons.tail` as `List<? extends T>` is so that you don't need to copy the whole list over, but just the first cons.) (As with #2, you'll probably want to centralize this in a private `upcast` method, which `Nil` and `Cons` can each implement appropriately.)

Comment: How does the compiler interpret the type List<? extends T>? Is it, in principle, a List<T>?

Comment: @GeorgeFoole: Sorry, I don't think I understand your question. Are you just asking what `List<? extends T>` means? (You used it in your question, so I was assuming you were already familiar with it; are you not?)